# How to do addition to a whole column in a sparse matrix in Python

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix `A` in Python and I want to add 14 to the first column.

`A[:,0] + 14`

However, I get an error message:

`NotImplementedError: adding a nonzero scalar to a sparse matrix is not supported`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an explicit column like this:

```
A[:, 0] = np.ones((A.shape[0], 1))*14 + A[:, 0]
```

Comment: If you are using a `csr_matrix` and have zeros on your first column, and you try the given approach, you get an `SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a csr_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar situation (as described in your question title) and after some research, I found that you can [manually change the shape of your matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695337/expanding-adding-a-row-or-column-a-scipy-sparse-matrix/17457226#17457226) but then, this doesn't look like the best solution, for this reason, I started a discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50457773/7454638) and my final solution was to manually create the sparse matrix (`ìndices`, `indptr` and `data` lists) so I could add new columns, rows and change the matrix sparsity at will.

The description of your question suggests a different problem, you don't want to add a new column, but to change the value of an element from the matrix. If this alters the matrix sparsity, I would suggest you have your own `ìndices`, `indptr` and `data` lists. If you want to modify a non-zero element, then you can change it directly without further problems.

Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28427236/set-row-of-csr-matrix/28430687#28430687) might be worth reading